# ветвь кода с if

Tags: c#

Всем привет, имеется вот такой if, у которого понятное дело есть else:

```
if(array[i].Equals(array[i+1])) //aaaabcaaaa
            { 
                count++; //count=4 //количество одинаковых повторений

                p = array[i]; //запоминаем какие именно буквы одинаковы -например несколько a подряд
                while(array[i].Equals(array[i + 1]))
                {
                            return true;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                flag_start = true; //нашли b и c
```

Компилятор ругается, что не все кода возвращают значение - я грешу на этот if который у меня был без return но проблема в том, что я не могу вернуть в нем определенное значение return т.к этот блок if можно считать - затравкой перед основным блоком else, в котором и происходит основная работа программы -т.е мне нужно возвращать определенное, в данном случае булево значение ждя данного блока if - пока его условие не станет ложным ион не перейдет в блок else. Для этого я вставил в блок if цикл while -который проверяет - тоже самое условие, что и блок if - т.е ложными они станут одновременно. Идея в чем - блок while будет возвращать true, пока блок if не вернет false и не перейдет к else - это может сработать или возвращаемое значение будет распространяться только для while? И еще такой вопрос, есть ли в Visual Studio - способ посмотреть, какая именно ветвь кода не возвращает значение - т.е какое либо представление или что-то типа Reflector?

Comment: Может через инверсию?  `!=` ...

Comment: простите - можете объяснить мысль?

Comment: Вам предлагают вместо `array[i].Equals(array[i+1])` написать один `if` без `else` с условием `array[i] != array[i+1]`

Comment: представьте, что в массиве нет стоящих рядом одинаковых значений - что в таком случае вернет функция? Вот это и поставьте в `return ...;` перед закрывающей `}` метода.

Comment: а если условие `while(array[i].Equals(array[i + 1]))` не выполнится, то вы не попадете в цикл, и, соответственно, ничего не вернете

Comment: по коду в примере блок else не закрыт

Comment: @Sv__t Благодарю :)

Comment: это кусок кода - поэтому и не закрыт

Comment: нет, средств для визуализации ветвей алгоритма в VS нет, есть только указания о том, что не все ветви возвращают значение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы правильно поняли что не нравится компилятору.
Я так понял, что у вас идет проблема в понимании.

Если вы пишете функцию, то она должна вернуть какое-то значение (случае void функций она просто должна завершится).

Вот что получится если разобраться в вашем алгоритме

[image: как работает ваша программа]

ветки 1,2 приведут к завершению программы 
ветка 3 нет
и если статический анализатор кода пропустит ваш код к этапу компиляции то возникнет ситуация, что при каких-то параметрах ваша программа пойдет по ветке 3, и тогда комп, грубо говоря, зависнет на мертво (хотя может быть какие-то системные функции могут его реанимировать)

давайте разберем следующий код

```
public class Program
{
    public static int test(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (a == b)
        {
            while(b == c)
            {
                count++; //ваши манипуляции с ответом 
                return count;
            }
            return count;
        }else{
            count = 99; //ваши манипуляции с ответом 
            return count;
        }
    }

    public static int test1(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (a == b && b == c)
            count++; //ваши манипуляции с ответом 
        if (a != b)
            count = 99; //ваши манипуляции с ответом 

        return count;
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test(0,0,0));
        Console.WriteLine(test(0,0,1));
        Console.WriteLine(test(0,1,0));
        Console.WriteLine(test(1,1,0));


        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");

        Console.WriteLine(test1(0,0,0));
        Console.WriteLine(test1(0,0,1));
        Console.WriteLine(test1(0,1,0));
        Console.WriteLine(test1(1,1,0));
        /* вывод
        1
        0
        99
        0

        1
        0
        99
        0*/
    }
}
```

Если в функции стоит if, то он пойдет по одной из 2 веток. И если внутри него вызвать return, то завершится вся функция а не блок if.
С while тоже самое.

В примере я написал функцию test, которая по логике похожа на вашу.
И есть функция test1, которая делает тоже самое

Заметьте как отличается код test и test1. В test1, есть переменная
count которая в конце всегда что-то возвращает, и она изначально инициализирована каким-то дефолтным значением, а в остальном теле функции происходят манипуляции с этим значением.
При разработке программ такая практика только плюсик к вашей карме даст.

Если хотите прервать выполнение while пишите правильные условия выполнения и не нужно будет ничего мудрить.

По поводу вашего последнего вопроса не знаю, я не пользователь VS

P.S. мне кажется вы явно делаете что-то не то (задание должно быть не сильно сложным и алгоритм очень простой)

Comment: Наверное да, но для меня сейчас главное практика - я учусь писать код самостоятельно - так сказать - первые шаги. И кстати, я тоже фанат Доктора)

Comment: @BadCats, а какая конкретно стоит задача ?

Comment: https://codefights.com/arcade/intro/level-1/s5PbmwxfECC52PWyQ

Comment: Суть задачи такова: дается на вход строка и если это строка вида "аабаа" - т.е читаемая с двух сторон одинаково, то вернуть true иначе false

Comment: строка подается на вход методу

Comment: @BadCats ссылка у вас не рабочая но такие строки называются палиндром  [статья на wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) алгоритм очень прост

Comment: @BadCats пример [кода](https://ideone.com/urquKo) выполняющий проверку

Comment: у меня почти тоже самое, только сложнее)))

Comment: Проще лучше. И для человека и для машины.)))

Comment: зависания не будет, даже если как-то обмануть компилятор (чисто теоретически), то при выходе из функции, произойдет ошибка при обращении в стек за полученным значением и программа просто аварийно завершит работу или, что еще хуже, программа продолжит работать с неверными данными, а ошибка произойдет позже, когда окажется, что программа уверена, что в стеке что-то есть, а там уже давно ничего нет.

Comment: @rdorn, да согласен, нарушится стек. А дальше не известно что произойдет. Спасибо за правки.